# I can't connect to AWS instance using AWS AD credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, rdp

I was following this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_tutorial_test_lab_base.html) to create an AWS managed Active Directory which also creates an EC2 instance already joined to a domain. I can connect via **RDP** with the local Administrator account using **Remmina**, but I can't connect to the instance using the **"Admin"** user from the AD.

I created another Windows Server 2016 instance and I joined it to a new domain, and created a Two-Way Trust Relationship.

AWS veryfies that the relationship is working correctly. I can ping and get responses from everywhere ( from instance 1 to the AD Server **corp.example.com**, From instance 1 to instance 2, from instance 2 to instance 1, and from instance 2 to the AD Server).

But I still can't connect to the instances using AD credentials via Remmina.

What is going on? Why can't I connect?

I still need everyone's help, please!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue when connecting RDP from Microsoft Remote Desktop Version 10.2.2 (1291), I downgraded to Version 8.0.44 (Build 30030) and it's now working.